# MVC 6 Identity ChangePassword for "SuperUser"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I need for "SuperUser" ability to change password of any user in identity system. I checked two solution.

1) add this one overloaded function to CustomUserManager for CRUD:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(TenantUser user, string newPassword)
    {...}
```

Use original function with token parameter, but this function in controller not working and return invalid token:

```
string Token = await manager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(TenantUser);
var resultPasswordChange = await manager.ResetPasswordAsync(TenantUser, Token, model.TenantUsersPassword.Password);
```

Custom user manager: All PRIVATE functions and  parameters has been already copied from orig UserManager to derived CustomUserManager. Resources for NotSupportedException are still not available... I'm not satisfacted with result...
Can you help me? What is better? Implement CustomUserManager or solve invalid token error? And please how to do?

Example what you need to copy for one more function (ChangePasswordAsync):

```
namespace Program.Models
{

public class TenantUserManager<TenantUser> : UserManager<TenantUser>, IDisposable where TenantUser : class
{
   // protected const string ResetPasswordTokenPurpose = "ResetPassword";
  //  protected const string ConfirmEmailTokenPurpose = "EmailConfirmation";



    private TimeSpan _defaultLockout = TimeSpan.Zero;
    private bool _disposed;
    private readonly HttpContext _context;
    private CancellationToken CancellationToken => _context?.RequestAborted ?? CancellationToken.None;



    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new instance of <see cref="UserManager{TenantUser}"/>.
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="store">The persistence store the manager will operate over.</param> 
    /// <param name="optionsAccessor">The accessor used to access the <see cref="IdentityOptions"/>.</param> 
    /// <param name="userValidators">A collection of <see cref="IUserValidator{TenantUser}"/> to validate users against.</param> 
    /// <param name="passwordValidators">A collection of <see cref="IPasswordValidator{TenantUser}"/> to validate passwords against.</param> 
    /// <param name="keyNormalizer">The <see cref="ILookupNormalizer"/> to use when generating index keys for users.</param> 
    /// <param name="errors">The <see cref="IdentityErrorDescriber"/> used to provider error messages.</param> 
    /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceProvider"/> used to resolve services.</param> 
    public TenantUserManager(IUserStore<TenantUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
    IPasswordHasher<TenantUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TenantUser>> userValidators,
    IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TenantUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
    IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<TenantUser>> logger, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger, contextAccessor)
    {

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the persistence store the manager operates over.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The persistence store the manager operates over.</value>
    protected internal IUserStore<TenantUser> Store { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="ILogger"/> used to log messages from the manager.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The <see cref="ILogger"/> used to log messages from the manager.
    /// </value>
 //   protected internal virtual ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    internal IPasswordHasher<TenantUser> PasswordHasher { get; set; }

    internal IList<IUserValidator<TenantUser>> UserValidators { get; } = new List<IUserValidator<TenantUser>>();

    internal IList<IPasswordValidator<TenantUser>> PasswordValidators { get; } = new List<IPasswordValidator<TenantUser>>();

    internal ILookupNormalizer KeyNormalizer { get; set; }

    internal IdentityErrorDescriber ErrorDescriber { get; set; }

    internal IdentityOptions Options { get; set; }






    public async Task<IdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(TenantUser user, string newPassword)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        var passwordStore = GetPasswordStore();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }
        var result = await UpdatePasswordHash(passwordStore, user, newPassword);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result;
        }
        return await UpdateUserAsync(user);
      //   Logger.LogWarning(2, "Change password failed for user {userId}.", await GeTenantUserIdAsync(user));
      //  return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.PasswordMismatch());            
    }


    private static string NewSecurityStamp()
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }


    private IUserSecurityStampStore<TenantUser> GetSecurityStore()
    {
        var cast = Store as IUserSecurityStampStore<TenantUser>;
        if (cast == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Resources.StoreNotIUserSecurityStampStore");
        }
        return cast;
    }



    // Update the security stamp if the store supports it
    internal async Task UpdateSecurityStampInternal(TenantUser user)
    {
        if (SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            await GetSecurityStore().SetSecurityStampAsync(user, NewSecurityStamp(), CancellationToken);
        }
    }

    internal async Task<IdentityResult> UpdatePasswordHash(IUserPasswordStore<TenantUser> passwordStore,
       TenantUser user, string newPassword, bool validatePassword = true)
    {
        if (validatePassword)
        {
            var validate = await ValidatePasswordInternal(user, newPassword);
            if (!validate.Succeeded)
            {
                return validate;
            }
        }
        var hash = newPassword != null ? PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, newPassword) : null;
        await passwordStore.SetPasswordHashAsync(user, hash, CancellationToken);
        await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user);
        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }


    private async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateUserInternal(TenantUser user)
     { 
         var errors = new List<IdentityError>(); 
         foreach (var v in UserValidators) 
         { 
             var result = await v.ValidateAsync(this, user); 
             if (!result.Succeeded) 
             { 
                 errors.AddRange(result.Errors); 
             } 
         } 
         if (errors.Count > 0) 
         { 
         //    Logger.LogWarning(13, "User {userId} validation failed: {errors}.", await GeTenantUserIdAsync(user), string.Join(";", errors.Select(e => e.Code))); 
             return IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray()); 
         } 
         return IdentityResult.Success; 
     } 


    private async Task<IdentityResult> ValidatePasswordInternal(TenantUser user, string password)
     { 
         var errors = new List<IdentityError>(); 
         foreach (var v in PasswordValidators) 
         { 
             var result = await v.ValidateAsync(this, user, password); 
             if (!result.Succeeded) 
             { 
                 errors.AddRange(result.Errors); 
             } 
         } 
         if (errors.Count > 0) 
         { 
          //   Logger.LogWarning(14, "User {userId} password validation failed: {errors}.", await GeTenantUserIdAsync(user), string.Join(";", errors.Select(e => e.Code))); 
             return IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray()); 
         } 
         return IdentityResult.Success; 
     } 



    private async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateUserAsync(TenantUser user)
     { 
         var result = await ValidateUserInternal(user); 
         if (!result.Succeeded) 
         { 
             return result; 
         } 
         await UpdateNormalizedUserNameAsync(user); 
         await UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(user); 
         return await Store.UpdateAsync(user, CancellationToken); 
     }




    private IUserPasswordStore<TenantUser> GetPasswordStore()
     { 
         var cast = Store as IUserPasswordStore<TenantUser>; 
         if (cast == null) 
         { 
             throw new NotSupportedException("Resources.StoreNotIUserPasswordStore"); //Resources are not awailable
         } 
         return cast; 
     }


    /// <summary> 
    /// Releases the unmanaged resources used by the role manager and optionally releases the managed resources. 
    /// <param name="disposing">true to release both managed and unmanaged resources; false to release only unmanaged resources.</param> 
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
     { 
         if (disposing && !_disposed) 
         { 
             Store.Dispose();
            _disposed = true;
        } 
     }


     protected void ThrowIfDisposed()
     { 
         if (_disposed) 
         { 
             throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name); 
         } 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, had to delete my answer - it is applicable for MVC 5, but I've totally missed that you are referring to the next version. And I've not had a chance to work with it properly.